# How do I make wget match exact domain names?

Tags: linux, wget

I'm using the following command to mirror a site:

```
wget -r -p -E -N -l 10 -k -nH -H -Dfoo.com,www.foo.com foo.com
```

The problem I am having is that somewhere on foo.com there are links to domains ending in foo.com (newfoo.com for example) and wget is also mirroring that site. Is it possible to limit the domains to an exact match? I don't want to crawl any subdomains other than www.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, wget does a soft match on accepted domains when crawling a site. For example all of the following domains would be match for foo.com:

- barfoo.com
- bar.foo.com
- anything.can.gohere.foo.com

I actually created a [patch](https://gist.github.com/offthecuff/358944ddc55fcb4e1776) for wget 1.15 to add an option to enable this strict matching behavior. Using this patch the entire domain must match exactly. It does not effect other lists of domains like excluded domains, etc.

Comment: This is disappointing but thanks for the answer and especially the patch.